# How can I fix deployment problems in quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to migrate project from SpringBoot to Quarkus.

Currently deps in module looks like this (+ some vertx deps):

```
plugins {
    id 'io.quarkus'
    id 'org.kordamp.gradle.jandex' version '0.7.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx'
    compile 'io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx-web'
    compile enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")

    compile "io.quarkus:quarkus-spring-boot-properties:${quarkusPlatformVersion}"
    compile 'io.quarkus:quarkus-spring-di'
    compile 'io.quarkus:quarkus-spring-web'

    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
}
```

As far as I understand, there is no need replacing spring annotations (except @SpringBootApplication).

Other test projects worked just fine, but in this case quarkusDev task fails with error:

```
2020-10-15 18:56:26,745 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Found 15 deployment problems: 
[1] Unsatisfied dependency for type com./.../.service.autoconfigure.MyProperties and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: com./.../.http.tracing.MyService#<init>()
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com./.../.http.tracing.MyService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com./.../.http.tracing.MyService]
```

And so on. Some failed deps from adjacent modules, others from external libs.
At this point I don't understand what causes this error.

MyProperties:

```
package com./.../.core.service.autoconfigure;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("grpc.client")
@ToString
public class MyProperties {
    private boolean abortOnCallCancel = false;
    private Map<String, ClientSettings> settings = new HashMap<>();
    private Long dynamicChannelCacheSize = 1000L;

    public ClientSettings getDefaultSettings() {
        return settings.get(ClientSettings.DEFAULT_KEY);
    }

    @Data
    public static class ClientSettings {
        public static final String DEFAULT_KEY = "default";
        private String hostname;
        private int port;
        private Long timeout;
        private Map<String, Object> serviceConfig = new HashMap<>();

    }
}
```

Comment: There are no quarkus extensions available for spring aop & webflux. You might not be able to migrate seamlessly.
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/4803

Comment: @Haroon, removed these deps (used to be unnecessary), still the same error.

Comment: Can you share `MyProperties`? Some dependency related to it is causing the issue probably.

Comment: Added to the issue. I think jandex is unable to scan beans in adjacent modules actually.